# Swift - iterating through characters in string causes memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

this is my very first post! I'm relatively new to Swift, and don't have a computer science background, so I'm still prone to a lot of newbie problems - but I've been able to solve them all so far, partly from browsing the excellent answers on StackOverflow. However, I've come across something that's really stumped me, and I've spend a whole week trying to solve it with no luck.

What I'm trying to do is take text in Chinese from a UITextView and then convert this to an array of individual Chinese characters, which is then used for various processing and analysis. However, this causes a leak.

In this greatly simplified example, which reproduces the same leak, there is a TextView and a Button; when the user presses the button, the function makeArray is called, which converts the text to an array of characters (actually Strings of single characters, because I need it to be strings for some of the stuff I will do with it). The class TextProcessing that contains this function is used as a singleton (yeah, I know that apparently singletons are supposed to be bad, for reasons I don't fully understand, but for various reasons involving other parts of the code it works best when there is a single instance of this class), and the text from the UITextView is passed into it, where it's then converted to the array, as you can see below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func pressDoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let textToAnalyze = textBox.text!
        TextProcessing.textProcessing.makeArray(textToAnalyze)
    }
}

class TextProcessing {
    static let textProcessing = TextProcessing()

    private let language = "Chinese"
    private var sourceTextArray: [String]!

    func makeArray (_ sourceText: String) {
        if language == "Chinese" {
            sourceTextArray = sourceText.characters.map { String($0) }
        } else if language == "English" {
            sourceTextArray = sourceText.components(separatedBy: " ")
        }
        // then do some stuff with this array
    }
}
```

When I run this on the Leaks Instruments I get leaks of "Malloc 16 Bytes" and "CFString", with the number of instances of each being roughly the same as the number of array elements (thus the number of characters in the string). When I look at the Call Tree and drill down, the problem line is "sourceTextArray = sourceText.characters.map { String($0) }".

By the way, this happens with relatively long texts - with short ones, either there's no problem or Instruments doesn't detect it.

However, if I make an array by separating the string into words according to spaces, like I would want in a language like English, there's no leak - so if I change the language variable to "English" in the example code, it works fine (but of course doesn't give me the array that I want). I thought that maybe the problem was in the "map" method, since it uses a closure and it's easy to have leaks with closures, but when I try other ways of putting it into an array of characters, such as using a for loop and iterating over each character that way, it still has the same problem.

If, instead of getting the text from the UITextView, I do this instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func pressDoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let textToAnalyze = "blah blah put a long string of Chinese text here"
        TextProcessing.textProcessing.makeArray(textToAnalyze)
    }
}
```

there's no problem. Likewise, if in the makeArray function, if I ignore sourceText and instead do this:

```
func makeArray (_ sourceText: String) {
    if language == "Chinese" {
        let anotherText = "blah blah some text here"
        sourceTextArray = anotherText.characters.map { String($0) }
    }
    // then do some stuff with this array
}
```

there's also no leak. So, something about the combination of getting the string from the text box, passing it into the function, and then putting it into an array of characters is causing the leak.

I've spent countless hours scouring the internet and reading everything about ARC in Swift, and I've tried all sorts of stuff with weak/unowned etc. and nothing seems to work. What's going on here and how could this be solved?

**Edit:**

So it appears that this might just be a problem with Simulator and/or Instruments. When I run it on the device, and just monitor memory usage in xcode debug, there's no increase even when doing it 100+ times, so I guess it's OK...it still seems weird that it would show a leak in Instruments though.

Comment: It works fine. I tried your code with a very long text - about a million Chinese characters :) - and no leak!

Comment: class TextProcessing { static let textProcessing = TextProcessing() }... I dont know if this is the problem, but you certainly don't need to reinstantiate this class as a class variable inside of itself. Object inception!

Comment: @3li That is strange...it consistently leaks every time I try it with anything longer than a few paragaphs. I'm using XCode 8.2.1 with Swift 3. What about memory allocations - even if it doesn't detect a leak for you, does the total memory keep increasing if you repeatedly press the done button?

Comment: @twiz_ Yeah, in this simplified example it looks weird and totally unnecessary to do it like this, but in my "real" code I have to use an instance of this class as a singleton throughout the lifetime of the app because of other stuff that it does - I'm just trying to follow best practices for singletons as described in https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton  Anyway, even when I change it and do it the "normal" way I still have the same memory leak issue, so this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instruments bug(there is a lot of issues). Your code is OK.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not totally sure. It certainly could just be a bug in the Leaks Instrument b ut when I run it in Allocations, the total memory steadily increases when I repeatedly press the button. Even when I don't run it in instruments at all, and just in Simulator, when I repeatedly press the button the total memory keeps going up and up...so clearly something is not working the way it should.

Comment: OK, so after some more testing, it seems like you may be right. The problem was I was only testing it on Simulator rather than on the device. When I test it on the device, the Leaks instrument still shows the same leak, and Allocations still shows the memory steadily going up, but when I run it on the device and just look at the memory in the xcode debug statistics, there's no increase in memory, even when I do it 100+ times. (in Simulator it shows the memory going up each time even in xcode) So, I guess this combination (xcode + device) is the most accurate, and therefore it's fine??? weird..

Comment: Yep it's strange. But instruments is a heavy tool, very difficult to write it without bugs. Also Xcode contain a lot of issues too :)

Answer (score 0):

I just filed a bug report (FB7684067).

The following simple macOS command line application will grow to over 1GB in only a few minutes:

```
import Foundation
let line = "124;5678;90123"
while true {
    let fields = line.components(separatedBy: ";")
    assert(fields[1] == "5678")
}
```

Comment: What was their reply? I'm trying to trace why a components separation by a character set is leaking inside an autorelease pool and I'm puzzled.